# Определение модуля по параметрам командной строки

Tags: shell, ruby, linux

Доброго дня!
Для выполнения моего скрипта/программы необходима следующая конструкция аргументов командной строки:

```
ruby shell.rb <module_name> <options_for_module>
```

Пример запуска приложения с для модулями backup и rpmbuild:

```
ruby shell.rb backup --dest=/mnt/backup --source=/var/www --exclude-list=list01 --gzip --ssh='user@foo.server.example.com'
ruby shell.rb rpmbuild --builddir=/home/rpm --tool=mock
```

Т.е.: Параметры идущие после имени модуля зависят от самого модуля и относятся только к нему, модуль я описал примерно так:

```
module Backup
...
  class OptparseBase
   ... # тут описание параметров
 end # class
end # module
```

Аргументы парсил с помощью optparse.

Проблема в том, что я не программист и у меня не получается придумать способа для чтения этих внешних модулей (Backup, Rpmbuild...) в зависимости от первого параметра. Еще бы хотелось сделать внутреннее разделение в самом модуле, например при запуске 
 `ruby shell.rb backup::freebsd [opt]` и `ruby shell.rb backup::linux [opt]` должны быть различные переменные или методы.

Надеюсь что понятно объяснил задачу, подскажите пожалуйста направление.

```
#Читать первый параметр, аперкейсить его и передавать в load #{name}.rb - это мне кажется слишком просто, думаю в ruby есть более красивое решение, за этим и обратился. #
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как все вариации делаются на основе первого аргумента, то можно проверять его вручную:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'optparse'

module_name = ARGV.shift
options = {}

if module_name == 'backup'
  OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.banner = "Usage: shell.rb backup::freebsd [options]"

    # opts.on ...
  end.parse!
elsif module_name == 'rpmbuild'
  OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.banner = "Usage: shell.rb backup::linux [options]"

    # opts.on ...
  end.parse!
else
  puts "Unknown module: #{module_name}"
  exit 1
end
```